# why Parameters read from a yaml file are null (c++/cmake)?

Tags: c++, cmake, yaml, g++

I have a class that reads a matrix (szMat) from a yaml file. when I compile the code with g++ command it works fine but when I use cmake the matrix value is 0. It does not get the actual values .
my cpp file

```
class Singleton
{
public:
    static Singleton *getInstance(); 
        static  Mat szMat;
  
private:
    Singleton(){}
    static Singleton* instance;
     
};
Mat Singleton::szMat;
Singleton* Singleton::instance=0;
Singleton* Singleton::getInstance() 
{
    if(!instance) {
           instance = new Singleton();
           
        // Read model file
        string modelFile("Parameters.yml");
        FileStorage file(modelFile, FileStorage::READ);
        
        instance->szMat = file["size"].mat();
    
        return instance;
    }
    else return instance;
    
    
} 
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{ Singleton *params = Singleton::getInstance();
 
  cout << params->szMat.size() << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

my CMakeLists.txt

```
#yaml 
find_package(yaml-cpp REQUIRED)
include_directories(${YAML_CPP_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_link_libraries(app PRIVATE protobuf::libprotobuf gRPC::grpc++ gRPC::grpc++_reflection ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${PostgreSQL_LIBRARIES} ${YAML_CPP_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: What are the contents of `Parameters.yml`? What does `file.isOpened()` return? And  `file["size"].type()`?

Comment: class `FileStorage` is [part](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/da/d56/classcv_1_1FileStorage.html) of OpenCV. Project `yaml-cpp` is unrelated.

Comment: the Parameters.yml contains objects calculated from pca model in cpp file that I will use them like the szMat. the problem is that when I compile this code with g++ command it works all fine but when I use cmake it does not get the matrix correct values. and I think the configuration in my cMakelists.txt is correct .

Comment: @Tsyvarev so why it does not get the real vaues?

Comment: I guess the file `Parameters.yml` simply hasn't been opened, because it is not located near the executable. (CMake creates executables in a directory, different from the directory with sources). As Thomas [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63632444/why-parameters-read-from-a-yaml-file-are-null-c-cmake?noredirect=1#comment112522668_63632444), you need to use `file.isOpened()` for check, whether the file has actually been opened.

Comment: I got it that was the problem ! thank you